# In a Godot 4 game, how to get the enemy to transition from path/roaming to chasing/attacking

Tags: gdscript

The enemy seems to be pulled towards the Path3D and won't leave it to go on the NavigationRegion to properly chase the player. I cannot disable it temporarily until the player has left chase area because it crashes the game.

See the comments in this code:

```
func _on_area_3d_body_entered(body):
    if body.is_in_group("Player"):
        player_detected = true
        print("Player entered")



func _on_area_3d_body_exited(body):
    if body.is_in_group("Player"):
        player_detected = false
        print("Player exited")

// This is the working code for enemy_area.

    if is_paused == true:
        match state_machine.get_current_node():
            "Run":

                nav_agent.set_target_position(player.global_transform.origin)
                var next_nav_point = nav_agent.get_next_path_position()
                velocity = (next_nav_point - global_transform.origin).normalized() * SPEED

                
                look_at(player.global_transform.origin, Vector3.UP)
                
                if _target_in_range():
                    state_machine.set("Attack", true)

                
            "Attack":
                look_at(Vector3(player.global_position.x, global_position.y, player.global_position.z), Vector3.UP)
                anim_tree.set("parameters/conditions/attack", _target_in_range())

                
                
                anim_tree.set("parameters/conditions/run", true)

                move_and_slide()
                if enemy_ray.is_colliding():
                    await get_tree().create_timer(0.5).timeout
                    attack_audio.play()
                    print("Can't make it.")
                    anim_tree.set("parameters/conditions/run", false)
                    anim_tree.set("parameters/conditions/attack", false)
                    anim_tree.set("parameters/conditions/spawn", true)
                else:
                    anim_tree.set("parameters/conditions/run", true)
                    anim_tree.set("parameters/conditions/attack", _target_in_range())
                    anim_tree.set("parameters/conditions/spawn", false)
    else:
        is_paused = true







func _target_in_range():
    return global_position.distance_to(player.global_position) < ATTACK_RANGE

// This code usually works for chasing and attacking the player.

@onready var enemy_ray = $EnemyRayCast3D
@onready var enemy_path = $".."
var path_follow_paused = false
var is_chasing_player = false

func  _ready():
    player = get_node(player_path)
    state_machine = anim_tree.get("parameters/playback")
    zombie_run.play()


func _physics_process(delta):
    if player_detected == false:
        enemy_path.progress += ROAM_SPEED * delta
    elif player_detected == true:
        is_paused = true
    else:
        is_paused = false



func _process(_delta):
    if player_detected == false:
        is_paused = false
    elif player_detected == true:
        is_paused = true
// And this is the nightmare.
```

I've tried about everything anim_tree parameters on player_detected which kind of worked but still pulled the enemy on to the Path and also made him float. I've tried a ton of stuff that I can't remember.